# Webhooks & Application Insight Alerts, possible?

Tags: azure-application-insights

When creating alerts in Application Insights, is it then possible to add a webhook in the same manner as you can do when creating alerts for metrics?

Like explained here: https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/blog/webhooks-for-azure-alerts/

Regards Niclas

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Webhooks integration is now available for metric-based alerts in Applications Insights. Details are here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/insights-webhooks-alerts.
We are working to add it to Availability alerts as well

---

Soon, we are working to plug Application Insights into this standard mechanism.

While Application Insights alerts are real Azure alerts, we do not automatically "inherit" every feature added to Azure alerts, but need to do some additional work to enable it. This is pretty high on our backlog, so stay tuned

Comment: Thanks Oleg. Please update this when you do have this available!

Comment: Webhooks support is now available - I updated my answer above